# What's the correct command to show all the processes being run by a user and their details?

Tags: linux, bash

I am testing my application and I need to make sure I am not leaving any zombie processes behind.

I tried **ps -u myuser** but it doesn't show all the info I want. How could I get this? This is the output I get but it doesn't include any details:

```
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
14283 ?        00:00:00 sshd
14284 pts/63   00:00:00 bash
14447 ?        00:00:00 sshd
14448 pts/65   00:00:00 bash
15427 pts/63   00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do for this is:

```
ps aux | grep "^myuser"
```

`ps aux` prints the process info, `grep "^myuser"` filters the output so you see only the lines (processes) that start the *myuser* user id

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
man ps
```

And read all about the many available options of the `ps` command, that will display additional information about each process.

Comment: It is somewhat nebulous to refer someone to a man page as an `answer`. While I agree with it, that is generally viewed as a comment.

Comment: Teaching someone how to fish, instead of giving him an already caught fish, is the best answer one could possibly expect.